# extra words in parentheses of a citation call-out generated with a natbib command

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I want to add some words inside the brackets of `natbib`. For example, I want to have something like `(e.g. someone, 1999, pp. 23--24)`. I can use `\citep[pp. 23--24]{...}` to get `(someone, 1999, pp. 23--24)`. My question is how to add `e.g.` inside the brackets. Could anyone help me, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `xyz` is the bib key to the entry that was written by `someone` in `1999`, you could write

```
\citep[e.g.,][pp.~23--24]{xyz}
```

to generate the following output: "(e.g., someone, 1999, pp.~23--24)".

Comment: Great, I did not know you can use two `[]`. But why `[e.g.,]` is put in front of the author but page numbers are at the end? Is this done by default?

Comment: @LaTeXFan - It's entirely up to you to choose what should be placed before and after the "someone, 1999" string. I fashioned my answer based on my understanding of your query. Is it not what you were looking for? Please advise.

Comment: Yes, it is what I am looking for. I am just wondering whether you could explain the underlying syntax. For example, where exactly to place the `[]`?

Comment: @LaTeXFan - Basically, if you provide a single `[...]` group to `\citep`, its material will be set *after* "someone, 1999", and nothing will be written before "someone, 1999". If you provide two bracketed groups, the first group's material will be typeset before and the second group's material will be typeset after "someone, 1999". That's what's shown in the answer I gave. If, for some reason, you need to provide some material before but no material after "someone, 1999", you'd leave the second group empty, i.e., you'd write something like `\citep[e.g.,][]{xyz}`.